# Is there a way to have the second <authentication mode="Forms"> somewhere in my sln?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have `<authentication mode="Windows">` in my web.config.

I do not want to create another solution with `<authentication mode="Forms">`, but I do need to allow external access to my intranet web app.

There is a way to allow Windows-Authentication-using-Form-Authentication described here

> http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Windows-Authentication-using-Form-Authentication.aspx.

Unfortunately, for the above to work, I still need

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
<forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
</forms> </authentication>
```

Is there a way to have the second `<authentication mode="Forms">` somewhere in my sln solution?

Comment: Fix your formatting.  All of the XML blocks are being stripped out and so it is hard to follow what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Microsoft ISA Server 2006. You can use it to enable Windows Authentication sessions through an html forms login page that stores a cookie on the client. To the ASP.NET web application, the user looks a Windows Authentication client. ISA Server maintains the mappings of forms authentication to Windows Authentication for you. I've worked on systems that use this with both SharePoint and ASP.NET Windows Authentication and it works great.